# How to POCO htttp server with a public acces to it?

Tags: c++, http, poco, poco-libraries

I has an HTTP server wirtten with POCO
I can test it with Postman while the server runing on my PC, and my colleagues PC ( we are all using same WIfi) its all good (ip adresses that i use is which i found in ipconfig comands in cmd)
The code is

```
Poco::UInt16 port = 80;
Poco::Net::SocketAddress SocAdress(Poco::Net::SocketAddress("18.216.18.158", port));
Poco::Net::ServerSocket socket(SocAdress);
```

But when i try to run it with my public ip adress (that i access with one of the myip.com services) it trow an error

```
NetException("Net subsystem not ready", code);
```

It happens on the line

```
Poco::Net::ServerSocket socket(SocAdress);
```

Comment: what is the code that goes with that exception?

Comment: and what OS?  I assume you are on Windows since you reference `ipconfig`.

Comment: you can lookup `WSASYSNOTREADY` here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2.

Comment: `WSAStartup` is called automatically from `Net.cpp`

Comment: You could create your socket using `SocketAddress(Poco::UInt16 port);` since that will accept connections from any ipAddr

Comment: @CookieButter The code of the error is 10049, but i dont realy understand why it is trowing becouse the port is 80 and the ip address is my public ip ?

Comment: I’m not really sure what you mean by, your public ip.  Is the up you are using available when you run ipconfig.  Maybe the port is already in use.  You can check it with netstat -a